# Combining Post-Quantum and Classical KEM

Tags: key-exchange, key-derivation, post-quantum-cryptography, hkdf, kem

I came across [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/903.pdf) paper "Hybrid Key Encapsulation Mechanisms", were three methods are defined that allow a secure combination of a classical key encapsulation with a post-quantum key encapsulation.

In terms of security and performance all three of them seem to be equally good.

For the second method, called "DualPRF Combiner", it is written:

> OurdualPRFcombiner is inspired by the key derivation in TLS 1.3
> [Res18] and models Whyte et al.’sproposal for supporting hybrid key
> exchange in TLS 1.3 [WFZGM17]. In TLS 1.3, HKDF’s extract functionis
> applied to the raw ECDH shared secret; the result is then fed through
> HKDF’s expand function with the(hashed) transcript as (part of) the
> label.

So I am asking myself, whether usage of a secure HKDF, such as HKDF with SHA2-512 woulf be sufficient as HKDF-extract and HKDF-expand would serve as dPRF and PRF from the combiner.

Comment: HKDF-Extract and HKDF-Expand together make up HKDF. You seem to be asking if you could use HKDF as function for HKDF-Expand, which would mean turning the algorithm inside out (and besides, HKDF-Expand has a clear definition and is build around HMAC).